# bash set env variable is not working in pdsh

Tags: bash, environment-variables, pdsh

I am using PDSH to control multiple servers through one command line.

The command below works fine on individual servers, but when I enter the export command within PDSH, echoing it back is empty.

Any ideas on why this is, or how to fix it?

**Specific example:**

This works just fine:

```
# export CRAWL_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d);
# echo $CRAWL_DATE
20131206
```

but in PDSH, it echos blank values:

```
pdsh> export CRAWL_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d);
pdsh> echo $CRAWL_DATE;
<IP 1>: 
<IP 2>:
```

Comment: You need to show exactly what you are executing.

Answer (score 4):

When I run the following command it appears to work just fine.

```
$ pdsh -w root@skinner,root@mulder \
    'export CRAWL_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d); echo $CRAWL_DATE;'
skinner: 20131206
mulder: 20131206
```

Running as you're describing shows this:

```
$ pdsh -w root@skinner,root@mulder
pdsh> export CRAWL_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d);
pdsh> echo $CRAWL_DATE;
skinner: 
mulder:
```

Running it this way works though:

```
pdsh> export CRAWL_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d); echo $CRAWL_DATE;
skinner: 20131206
mulder: 20131206
```

#### So why didn't method #2 work?

The likely reason is that each time you run a command in `pdsh` and hit return that command is executed via `ssh` on each host. The next command that is executed is run in an entirely different `ssh` session with a different shell, so the variable doesn't exist.

This issue that was filed in 2011 I think gives credence to my conclusion. [Issue 37: Support user defined variables in pdsh](http://code.google.com/p/pdsh/issues/detail?id=37).

There was an interesting workaround mentioned in that issue, mainly:

```
$ pdsh -w ^hostfile -Rexec ssh -2 -l %u %h '. ~/.pdsh/vars/%h; command'
```

This method makes use of a file that would contain the variables, and each command could then source this file, `. ~/.pdsh/vars/%h` each time a command is run remotely.

Comment: My guess would be that in method 2, it's running each command in a different shell.

Comment: @jordanm - mine too. I'm looking into the setting of variables using pdsh now. That seems to be where the smoke is coming from.

Comment: @jordanm - there is this feature request which makes me believe that the exporting of variables isn't supported, because each command is run as a `ssh` each time you hit return.

Comment: exported environment variables are not persisted between sessions.  In method2, each command is batched out in a fresh ssh session.